# Isomorphism A to B or B to A?

Tags: group-theory, group-isomorphism

Let G and H be groups, and let f : G → H be a homomorphism. Then:

1. The kernel of f is a normal subgroup of G,
2. The image of f is a subgroup of H, and
3. The image of f is isomorphic to the quotient group G / ker(f).

In particular, if f is surjective then H is isomorphic to G / ker(f).

Source: [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isomorphism_theorems)

Whereas in gallian for the third property it says "G/ker(f) is isomorphic to image of f"

Are both the same thing? A isomorphic to B iff B isomorphic to A?

Comment: The inverse of any isomorphism $A \to B$ is an isomorphism $B \to A$.

Comment: the mapping will be different right?

Comment: @ngbtwby Yes the maps are (usually) different. In fact they must be, whenever the elements of one group are of a different type from those of a second isomorphic group. [One has to reverse the ordered pair to get the inverse map.]

Comment: Yes. The mapping will be the inverse mapping, which exists since the original isomorphism is a bijection.

Comment: [Here's a MathJax tutorial](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) :)